# Importing the Cordova plugin

Tags: typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3, phonertc

I am creating a real time audio calling app using phoneRTC in ionic3.

I have added the cordova plugin using following command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-phonertc --save
```

Which adds following lines to my package.json

```
"cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "com.dooble.phonertc": {}
        }
    }
```

and following to config.xml

```
<plugin name="com.dooble.phonertc" spec="~2.0.1" />
```

Now, i don't know how to use or import this in my home.ts file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `phonertc` is not a native plugin you have to use it like this:

**.ts**

```
declare var cordova;

@Component({
})
export class Page2 {

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {

  }

  getMyPluginInfo() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {//this is very important

      cordova.plugins.yourPlugin.YourPluginMethod();//replace plugin's name with this `yourPlugin` and `YourPluginMethod` with plugin's method which you want

    });
  }
}
```

**Note:**

If above method won't work you can try another method which has been explained in [**this article**](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/).(see it under the title `Using a Plugin Not Included in Ionic Native`)